# Securing WCF Data Services Metadata

Tags: metadata, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service (5.6) running in a Webrole in an azure cloud service. I do not want to disclose the metadata, however regardless of how I set the behavior it still returns the metadata.

this is the snippet from the web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"  httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  
               Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

...

Any help is greatly appreciated

Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to expose the metadata, try removing the `<serviceMetadata>` node altogether.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yeah, i tried that. I actually tried a lot more. Regardless it still shows metadata when i put $metadata behind. I wonder if it has something to do with the bindings...

Comment: Can you show your "mex" endpoint as well?  Does it reference a `behavior` by name?  If so, the problem might be that your `behavior` tag doesn't have a `name` attribute.

Comment: I have put the WCF Data service on hold as i think that WebApi will allow more flexibility in my project. No I was not referencing a behaviour by name, and I am currently rereading the bindings documentation to see if I need to actually be specific. Thank you for your help. I'll mark the question as answered anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of words seems to imply that you feel the metadata is somehow sensitive and should be protected. This would be completely wrong. If I may suggest that this could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), could you explain why you need to "secure" it?

If your needs encompass aspects other than security, then please do ignore this, but whatever you do, remember that this metadata is in great part what makes OData useful in the first place. Thanks to it, clients don't need to redefine data models (at least for their DAL/DTOs) which can instead be automagically generated on the fly and kept in sync with the server. When done manually, this usually involves a lot of work for all your client software developers.